# Anchor tag issue - href and click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have anchor link with click and href events. I need to run click event first then once complete the event it should call href to access action class. I have updated the sample code in jsfiddle like complete the click event , it should forward to stackoverflow.com. But its not forwarding after click.

Please advise.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div.actions").append('<a id="excelExport" class="actionButton" alt="Export to Excel" title="Export to Excel" href="listexport">click me</a>');
    $('div.actions').on('click', '#excelExport', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        callajax();
    });
});

function callajax() {
    jQuery.ajax({
 url : '',
     data : 

}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/g30rg3/u5k95/3/)

Comment: That's because you are using [`e.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) _If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered._

Answer (score 1):

Since you prevent the link, you need to send this.href to the CallAjax function and do `location=href` in the success method

This is of course assuming you'll change the alert to an Ajax call later

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KqRPt/1/)

```
    callajax(this.href);


function callajax(href) {
    var URL = href;
    $.get("something",{"URL":URL },function(URL){
    // url is returned from server
    location.href=URL;
  });
}
```

OR

```
function callajax(href) {
    var URL = href;
    $.get("something",{"URL":URL },function() { // reuse url passed to function
    location.href=URL;
  });
}
```

Comment: After ajax call , href action for access the action class method.So accessing method also location.href will work ?

Comment: In my example I return the href from the server again, you do not have to